# NodeJS Post Request Body Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, post, request

I'm making a simple post request to an API that retrieves 401 and a challenge token in its body.

If I do with:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -d '{
"username" : "dummydata"}' "<BASER_URL>/authentication"
```

I can get the desired token, tried the same for php and python and also get a token within the body of the request, however I cant find to make this work with nodejs, tried axios,request & unirest and got the same result.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var request = require('request');


var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: '<BASE_URL>/authentication',
  headers:
   { 'cache-control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'application/json'
    },
  body: {username: "dummydata"},
  json: true };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log(body)
});
```

**EDIT**

**`console.log(error)`**

```
error: null
```

**`console.log(response)`**

```
response:{
    "statusCode": 401,
    "headers": {
        "set-cookie": [
            "X-HSC-PREFIX=d063b4009759",
            "JSESSIONID=08C30E33724CB79C85491B4494F0068B; Path=/HsAPI/; HttpOnly"
        ],
        "transfer-encoding": "chunked",
        "server": "Apache-Coyote/1.1",
        "connection": "close",
        "date": "Thu, 23 Mar 2017 17:23:12 GMT",
        "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    "request": {
        "uri": {
            "protocol": "https:",
            "slashes": true,
            "auth": null,
            "host": "",
            "port": 443,
            "hostname": "",
            "hash": null,
            "search": null,
            "query": null,
            "pathname": "",
            "path": "/",
            "href": ""
        },
        "method": "POST",
        "headers": {
            "cache-control": "no-cache",
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "accept": "application/json",
            "content-length": 42
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what are the outputs of `console.log(error)` and `console.log(response)` in your request callback?

Comment: updated the post @chukkwagon

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this, @MuckFelo?